# Indy 10 - IdHTTP.Get raising "Could not load SSL library"

Tags: delphi, ssl, openssl, indy

In my application I am using IdHTTP.Get. A part of the code:

```
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
begin
  IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  Output := IdHTTP.Get(url);
  ...
  IdHTTP.Free;
```

Using IdHTTP.Version gives me the version: 10.6.2.5263

I have downloaded the OpenSSL from [here](http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/), both libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll are in the same folder of my application.

This problem occured since I am using a new laptop with Windows 10.
I hope someone can tell me how to solve this problem!

Comment: Use Indy's `WhichFailedToLoad()` function in the `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders `unit to find out which DLL failed to load.

Comment: Check the firewall settings for (application-specific) block of outgoing connections

Comment: @whosrdaddy thanks, it appears that only libeay32.dll failed to load

Comment: @mjn I turned off the firewall and tried, but it didn't help

Comment: @Teun: what *exactly* is `WhichFailedToLoad()` returning?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: "Failed to load libeay32.dll."

Comment: That means either libeay32.dll could not be found, or it could not be loaded into memory by `SafeLoadLibrary()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: libeay32.dll is in the same folder as ssleay32.dll so I guess it can be found. What can cause the not loading into memory by SafeLoadLibrary()?

Comment: @Teun: By default, Indy loads the OpenSSL DLLs using relative paths, so Windows' [DLL Search Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx) takes affect. If needed, Indy does have an `IdOpenSSLSetLibPath()` function to specify a specific folder instead. Either way, to find out why `SafeLoadLibrary()` is failing, you would have to call it directly and then see what `GetLastError()` reports.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem. I have removed the earlier downloaded OpenSSL and downloaded the OpenSSL from this site:
http://external.informer.com/slproweb.com/
there I downloaded and installed Win32 OpenSSL v1.0.2f Light and that appears to have solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

If you need to access an https url, you must add some code, to complete the creation of the `TidHTTP` component.

Try use something like this:

```
// create components
HTTPs := Tidhttp.Create(nil);
IdSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket.Create(nil);
// try..finally for free
try
  // ini
  HTTPs.ReadTimeout := 30000;
  HTTPs.IOHandler := IdSSL;
  IdSSL.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
  IdSSL.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
  IdSSL.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
  ...
```

You need to add `IdSSLOpenSSL` to uses clause.

Comment: The code I mentioned worked for me in the past and it still does on other computers I use. It only doesn't on my new laptop. So I assume the code is not the problem.

Comment: See http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/blogs/ChangeLog/20141222.en.aspx, the IOHandler creation code is not required for simple use cases

Comment: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket = TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL in the newest indy version

Comment: I added the extra properties to the IOHandler, but I am still getting the Could not load error.

Comment: Check that the version of the DLLs is correct. Many mistakes are due to this.

Answer (score 0):

Having 32 bit target platform for your application in a 64 bit system will also cause this problem. I don't know how to properly fix this but an easy way is to compile exe for same system your OS is.

Answer (score 0):

After trying the various solutions offered here, none of them work with the latest version of Windows 10 or Windows 11.
I would like to share my solution that works:

Just install the latest version of open SSL ***openssl-1.0.2u-x64_86-win64*** which is available [here](https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/).

It includes the two necessary libraries for TidHTTP libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll in version 1.0.2.21

Comment: I tried your solution but it was not work for me. I have downloaded and copied these are two files into my application directory but my program send the same error message than your meessage. "Could not load SSL library." Do you have any idea about this issue?

Comment: FYI, the official place to get the DLLs nowadays is from Indy's GitHub repo: https://github.com/IndySockets/OpenSSL-Binaries That said, use Indy's `WhichFailedToLoad()` function to tell you WHY the DLLs failed to load.